# Uploading files to google docs

Tags: javascript, grails, google-docs

Has anyone implemented a solution to upload files to google docs (under google apps domain) from a grails application?

Are there any pure javascript solutions? I'd like to avoid posting the file to the server side in order to do the upload.

What is the recommended approach?

Did you use any of the Grails file upload plugins?

Did you have to configure anything on the google apps account to allow you to upload files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard of a plugin, but you can use the Google API client: https://code.google.com/apis/documents/

I haven't this particular library, but I've used the one for managing calendars and the one for Google Analytics. Their APIs are very well documented and have lots of sample code, so it should be easy to get started.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd seen the api and was looking for the easy option where someone had wrapped it in grails goodness.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to step up and do that :)